# What is the source for the time of Isha and Maghrib in degrees of the sun?

Tags: practical-islam, prayer-timings

Ive heard people say that the time of isha is when the red glow dissapears from the western sky, Ive heard some people say this is when the sun is at 13 degrees however Ive heard other people say this is when the sun is at 12 degrees. I am trying to find the source for this? Where is the source that gave these amount of degrees?
I am also wondering about the Shia tradition for the Maghrib prayer which is when the redness disappears from the Eatern sky, do we know how many degrees the sun is at this point?

Comment: These are based on the scientific approach of creating a model for the prayer time calculation after comparing it with observations and all possible factors there might be some early attempts but this topic was not necessary for Muslims before electric lights etc as external factors who have influences on correct sky observation were invented.

Answer (score 0):

The degrees of the sun are derived by calculation and observation of the [visual signs](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76441/) which are present in ahadith. There is no hadith which says x degrees or y degrees.

Comment: So  who was the first to give an amount based on degrees? I'm looking for the first source for this?